# Regex Find Pattern of 4 Characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm confused how to do this.
I have an array of strings that match this pattern:

```
AABC,
ABBC,
ABCC,
AAAB,
ABBB
```

I'm hoping to use regex to figure out if a particular string matches one of these patterns. The strings themselves do not actually consist of A, B, or C. This is just to show how the pattern looks like. For example:
Pattern AAAB should not equal BAAA.

Can you help?

Edit - For example:

```
['TTES', 'TEES', 'TESS', 'TTTE', 'TEEE']
```

array[0] should match AABC,

array[1] should match ABBC,

array[2] should match ABCC,

array[3] should match AAAB,

array[4] should match ABBB,

Comment: Why don't you just do `arrayOfStrings.includes(testString)`?

Comment: I don't see how that'd work... Unless I type out every possible strings...

Comment: can you give your sample `input` and `outputs` to get better understanding.

Comment: Sorry. I edited the question, hopefully that's more clear.

Comment: @cocacrave - Just trying to formulate a problem statement here because this issue seems complicated. I guess what OP is trying to look for is the amount of unique characters within a string and how are these unique characters positioned. Then test it against a comparer string to see if such pattern or not.

Comment: @SamuelToh Yeah just looking to see if a string matches certain pattern I listed as AABC etc. above. Adam answered the question below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could generate `RegExp` from your patterns this way:

```
var stringToPattern = function (string) {
    var regexString = string.split('').map(function (char, position, string) {

        var prevIndex = string.indexOf(char);

        return prevIndex < position ? '(\\' + (prevIndex + 1) + ')' : '(.)';

    }).join('');

    return new RegExp(regexString);
};
```

The function generates a regular expression based on the input string:

- `AABC` to `/(.)(\1)(.)(.)/`
- `ABBC` to `/(.)(.)(\2)(.)/`
- etc...

Examples:

```
stringToPattern('AABC').test('TTES'); // true
stringToPattern('AABC').test('TEES'); // false

stringToPattern('ABBC').test('TEES'); // true
stringToPattern('ABBC').test('TTES'); // false
```

**update**

```
var getMatchingPatterns = function (string) {
    var patterns = [
        'AABC',
        'ABBC',
        'ABCC',
        'AAAB',
        'ABBB'
    ];
    return patterns.filter(function (pattern) {
        return stringToPattern(pattern).test(string);
    });
};
```

examples:

```
getMatchingPatterns('ttob'); // ['AABC']
getMatchingPatterns('ottb'); // ['ABBC']
```

Comment: Thanks! I have no clue how this works though, but it works. Can you explain it a little bit? Also, is it possible to return the pattern in AABC form for TTES instead of using test method to return true/false?

Comment: I've updated the answer to be a bit more clear. I don't really understand your second question. What do you exactly want?

Comment: So for example: if I run `stringToPattern('TTES')` then it should return `'AABC'`. Right now it retuns true or false, but I'd like to return the actual string (pattern in A/B/C) so that I don't have to run the .test method 4 times to see which one it returns true.

Comment: Oh that's amazing. Thank you so much.